# linked option with g++

Tags: c++, c, g++, shared-libraries

I have a shared library which needs to be loaded in my java application.

my shared library "libabc.so" code uses API's of 
another shared library "libxyz.so"

though i am providing the declaration of those API's via header files to my library,

when i built my shared library "libabc.so" with

g++ -shared -Wall -pthread -lrt

java application is not able to load the library.
whereas if i built it with
g++ -shared -Wall -pthread -lrt -lxyz , it gets loaded successfully.

in both options, library is generated without any error reported though.
but for the second option, i should have the libxyz.so available in the environment whereever i am building my library.
is there any alternative? am i missing something here?

Comment: so my intention here to build the libabc.so which can be loaded in my java application without -lxyz option to g++. if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid this will not be possible. If you are building a shared library that depends on another shared library library, you will have to explicitly state this dependency. Otherwise it is impossible for the dynamic linker/loader to resolve all dependencies.

If you want to get rid of the dependency and if you have access to the sources of libxyz.so (or libxyz.so is also available as libxyz.a - a static library), you can try to bundle them into libabc.so.